# How to get a convinced outcome from Random Forest classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest

I use Python to run a RandomForestRegressor on my dataset. It usually happened that every set of result (estimators, feature importance, ROC score, accuracy score etc.) from a single run is different from others. Let's set apart the issue of parameter tuning, how can I get the convinced outcome from various running output? Do I choose the one with highest ROC score?

To be generalize the question, how to identify the best result from algorithms which give varying outcome from different iteration of running?

Thanks

Comment: "Convinced"? That doesn't make sense. Do you mean some other word?

Comment: Random forest is **random.** If runs with the same parameter configuration differ widely, this indicates large variance of the RF estimator ("large" is context dependent/application specific). So you need to take steps to reduce the variance such as increasing the number of trees. Like everything else in statistics, a point estimator without an estimate of error is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cross-validation to get the parameters of the Random forests (RF) model. The important parameters in an RF model are the number of trees, the maximum depth of trees and the minimum size of a leaf.
Use a portion (may be 50%) of the dataset for this.

Now after finding the optimal parameters, use them to develop RF model via cross-validation.

Report the results from this cross validated setting. The change between the runs will be very small and wont be significant.

You may also run the cross-validation multiple times and report the average result.

Answer (score 0):

The different outcomes are (probably) a result from initializing your Random Forest with a different seed.

Normally the outcomes should not differ that much, if they do, try to increase the number of trees of your forest.

Another possibility is to take the average of the various outcomes, which will allow you to make a proper estimation of the outcome and to generate a confidence along with your prediction scores.